# What is the StandardError brother class in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mongoid

I would like to know the `StandardError` brother in Mongoid.

I don't know whether exists or not!. I can not find it in http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Errors/MongoidError

Comment: what is a brother? `MongoidError` is a Child (subclass) of `StandardError` and it appears all the errors raised are children (sublclasses) of `MongoidError`. As is evident by this line *"Default parent Mongoid error for all custom errors."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/tree/master/lib/mongoid/errors) you can see all of the error classes in mongoid. If you check them you will see that all of them are based on `Mongoid::Errors::MongoidError`. So I believe that's the "StadardError brother" in mongoid.

Another way to find it is to use method `ancestors` to see class hierarchy of the particular class. So you can do something like this:

```
begin
  1/0  
rescue StandardError => e  
  puts e.class.ancestors
end

=>ZeroDivisionError
StandardError
Exception
ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Blamable
Object
PP::ObjectMixin
ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable
V8::Conversion::Object
JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object
Kernel
BasicObject
```

That is a full ancestry tree and you can get base error class from there.